# How do I create a type that hosts a list of items, that implement an interface, but have different typed parameters?

Tags: f#

How do I create a type that hosts a list of items, that implement an interface, but have different typed parameters?

Specifically, I need a container to hold a list of interfaces that have typed parameters that vary.

**Note:**

The types are not predetermined. Thus, I don't think I can use discriminated unions for generic type parameters that I can't foresee.

Is it possible?

```
    let syncItem1 = { someSyncItem1 with Subscribers = seq {someResponder1} }
    let syncItem2 = { someSyncItem2 with Subscribers = seq {someResponder2} }

    let engines = seq [Engine(seq {syncItem1}) :> IEngine<int,string>
                       Engine(seq {syncItem2}) :> IEngine<string,int> // Compile error

                      ] |> MultiEngine
```

**Error:**

> *All elements of a list must be of the same type as the first element, which here is 'string'. This element has type 'int'.*

Appendix:

[GitHub](https://github.com/bizmonger/SyncEngine/blob/master/SyncEngine/SyncEngine.fs)

Comment: What functionality do the interfaces provide? Is this for messaging or event handling?

Comment: The interface was intended to serve as a container for accessing different types of SyncItems uniformly. However, I failed.

Comment: Check this post it may or may not be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012421/defining-a-message-passing-domain-with-very-many-message-types/54015593#54015593

Comment: How is `IEngine<_,_>` declared? What methods does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. `IEngine<int, string>` and `IEngine<string, int>` are, on a type-theoretical level, completely unrelated types and putting them in the same list makes no sense.

If there is a reasonable way that an engine can be used regardless of its parameters, extract that functionality into a parameterless superinterface and make the list typed to that.

If there is no reasonable way to do that, you can't do polymorphic dispatch anyway, so you need type tests and might as well use a list of `Object` too.